# Converting a Hyper-V VM with a vhdx drive to a VMWARE format

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, vmware-vsphere, hyper-v-server-2012

We've been looking at converting virtual machines from Hyper-V 2012 which use .VHDX drives into a vmware-compatible format.

So far, we haven't found any tools that can actually do this.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no VMware tools exist that directly convert VHDX disks yet. What you can do is power on the VM and treat it as a P2V migration using Converter and migrate that way.

Answer (score 9):

If you would like to convert only the virtual disk, not entire VM, you can also use qemu-img for Windows: it's free, portable and it runs under CMD.

For example, to convert VHDX to VMDK:

```
qemu-img.exe convert FileSource-Image.vhdx -O vmdk FileDestination-Image.vmdk
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/08/vmware-convertir-vhdx-en-vmdk.html

Answer (score 3):

Convert to .VHD then use [StarWind V2V Converter](http://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter).

Comment: Would Starwind convert the settings xml with the device drive definitions as well, or just the disk drives ?

Comment: Just the disks as afar as I know.

Answer (score 3):

Am I missing something? The VMware Converter should do this. Run the VMware Converter and start a task to convert the Hyper-V VM just as you would convert a physical machine. The converter doesn't care what the underlying disk format is and it doesn't care whether the machine being converted is physical or virtual.

Now if you're talking about only converting the VHD file instead of the entire VM then that's another story.

In addition, if you need to go in the other direction and don't want to deal with SCVMM, Microsoft makes a standalone converter to convert VMware VM's to Hyper-V:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34591

Comment: yes. You are missing the fact s/he said nothing about the VMs to be converted. Non-windows VMs => no vmware converter. VMware seem to have removed the earlier "cold clone" isos from their site.

Answer (score 1):

While the VM itself can not be converted the VHD can be converted using WinImage. So the solution is to convert the VHD file to VMDK format and then attach it to a new VMware virtual Machine.